# Instantiate game object script not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new at coding and I'm trying to write a script that spawns a specific game object from a spawn point, but I keep getting errors saying:
'GameObject' is a type but is used like a variable
'Mouse' does not contain a definition for 'AddComponent'
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Component.transform'

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnMouse : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Mouse;
    public Transform SpawnPoint;
    public Vector3 Pos;
    public Quaternion Rot;

    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
        {
            Pos = SpawnPoint.position;
            Rot = SpawnPoint.rotation;
            GameObject mouse = Instantiate(Mouse, Pos, Rot)as GameObject;
        }


    }

}
```

Anyone know why I keep getting these errors? Thanks!

Comment: There should be a space here: `Instantiate(Mouse, Pos, Rot)as` between the `)` and `as`...

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would cause these errors, are you giving us the entire context of the issue? When Unity gives you errors it will tell you the line numbers associated with the error.

Comment: Oh my god that's annoying, adding the space fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeBell if that really was the issue, post an answer. That's really obscure.

Comment: Have you tried double clicking on the error? Also you haven't included the full scope of the issue, because you have an error about components but have shown nothing about components in your code. My guess is that both of you errors don't have to do with the code you posted.